# Shopify - detecting metafields

Tags: html, e-commerce, shopify

Very new to [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) and wondered if anyone could help me. I've some products listed that when clicked should provide a link to an affiliate as opposed to the add to cart button. To create the affiliate option I used Metafield Solid to add the affiliate link data:

```
   Key:url
   Namespace: affiliate
```

In the themes (Minimal) I made the following changes:

```
<!-- Affiliate metafield contains? {{ product.metafields.affiliate.url }} -->

      <div class="purchase-section{% if product.variants.size > 1 %} multiple{% endif %}">
        <div class="purchase">

          {% if product.metafields.affiliate.url %}

         <a target="_blank" href="{{ product.metafields.affiliate.url }}" />Buy from Affiliate</a>

          {% else %}

<!-- this would be your original button -->

         <input type="submit" id="add-to-cart" class="btn" name="add" value="{{ 'products.general.add_html' | t | escape }}" />

         {% endif %}
```

When I preview the page it still shows the Add to cart button, yet when I view the source the comment containing product.metafields.affiliates.url clearly shows the correct affiliate URL. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: You have affiliates and affiliate did you check that s? @Meeesta

Comment: Ooops edited that typo. Sorry about that, it is affiliate in the original code.

Comment: No, the typo was only in the what I typed into stackoverflow, the original code contained no typo - I know I should have copy pasted, I'll go sit on the naughty step.

Comment: @Meesta see that you're somewhere looping into variants. Are you sure you're always calling product metafield and that you have the metafield inside the product metafield? Remember that you can also add metafields inside variants.